# Given this XML, is there an xpath that will give me the 'test' and 'name' values?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to get the value of the 'test' attribute in the xsl:when tag, and the 'name' attribute in the xsl:call-template tag.   This xpath gets me pretty close:

```
..../xsl:template/xsl:choose/xsl:when
```

But that just returns the 'when' elements, not the exact attribute values I need.

Here is a snippet of my XML:

```
<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@name='First Name'">
        <xsl:call-template name="handleColumn_1" /> 
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve Cooper answered the first part.  For the second part, you can use:

```
.../xsl:template/xsl:choose/xsl:when[@test="@name='First Name'"]/xsl:call-template/@name
```

Which will match specifically the xsl:when in your above snippet.  If you want it to match generally, then you can use:

```
.../xsl:template/xsl:choose/xsl:when/xsl:call-template/@name
```

Answer (score 2):

do you want `.../xsl:template/xsl:choose/xsl:when/@test`

If you want to actually get the value 'First Name' out of the test attribute, you're out of luck -- the content inside the attribute is just a string, and not a piece of xml, so you can't xpath it. If you need to get that, you must use string manipulation (Eg, substring) to get the right content

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I'm looking for, and I know I can't parse out the @name= value, I can do that after I get the data back from my xpath operation.

What about getting the name value from the call-template?

thank you!

Comment: Actually I need to end up having the "handleColumn_1" value somehow associated with the "@name='First Name'" value... so if there is anything that will get me closer to that, that would be great.